# Invalid json in request body using ionic push

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Couldn't find what's wrong with my req object. I got this error when trying to send push notification in the callback. Tried to link my request data using jslint.com, nothing wrong with it. Been scratching head for hours for this!

> {"link": null, "message": "Invalid JSON in request body. For empty
>   JSON, pass '{}'.", "type": "UnprocessableEntity"}

my code as below :

```
var title = req.body.title,
  message = req.body.message;

// Define relevant info
var ionic_api_token = 'eyJ0eXAiOTdGb-xQVQaD2sV7qTh7XNKCnwiJKV1QiLJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI2MjiNC03YjE5LTQ3MzMtYjJhMy0zM2Y3MjBkYzU4MjcifQ.s3e6pCwlVUBAs8kvbO';
var device_tokens = ['d44pDarVamnNJS2cNJ2modyBxjZZxcHLlnhQN4wZkJdbgkOw96rq9EEv2WCA5MKU6do0pJoO5rsmQsBAecFt4OIFB0hhD4Dp2K-uMbjum828j-8LKtpCTtGoIDBUvYI6L'];
var ionic_security_profile = 'main';

// Build the request object
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ionic_api_token
  },
  data: {
    "tokens": device_tokens,
    "profile": ionic_security_profile,
    "notification": {
      "title": title,
      "message": message,
      "android": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      },
      "ios": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      }
    }
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body)
}

request(req, callback);

});
```

Comment: is it something to do with the response? could you share the response json from your network console?

Comment: @Nannakuhtum I already shared. here is the full response : `{"meta": {"status": 422, "version": "2.0.0-beta.0", "request_id": "28ac473b-ea54-4e7a-bd69-"}, "error": {"link": null, "message": "Invalid JSON in request body. For empty JSON, pass '{}'.", "type": "UnprocessableEntity"}}
`

Comment: escape 'title' and 'message'. I am adding a answer too..

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that could cause problem are the title & message objects(probably string). Please try escaping it, like below

```
function escapeJson(json) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
}

title = escapeJson(title);
message = escapeJson(message);

var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ionic_api_token
  },
  data: {
    "tokens": device_tokens,
    "profile": ionic_security_profile,
    "notification": {
      "title": title,
      "message": message,
      "android": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      },
      "ios": {
        "title": title,
        "message": message
      }
    }
  }
};
```